# Phaser arcade physics, use overlap to switch only once but keeps firing

Tags: javascript, game-physics, phaser-framework

I'm working on an action game using the Phaser framework, and I want the player to be able to touch certain switch tiles to turn other enemies off and back on. So it should work like this:

1. The player overlaps a special switch tile
2. Execute the switch action, **only once**
3. Ignore further overlapping until player moved off of the tile
4. When player moves off a switch tile, only then should it start checking for overlap again
5. Repeat from step 1 when player overlaps again (or another switch tile)

I'm using arcade physics and the overlap function is working. But the problem is that the overlap keeps firing over and over again, like every single frame. What would be the best way in Phaser to get the desired result?

See screenshot below of what I mean, and I've created a sandox of my code example here:
https://phaser.io/sandbox/edit/zEVOQfgA

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not working because you are resetting `okoverlap` to `0` on each `update`. What you need to do is to set the `okoverlap` to a state and change that state at suitable time.

I've fixed your code by saving the property in `game` object in `create`.

```
game.flags = {};
game.flags.okoverlap = 0;
```

Then in `update` function I've checked that property and current overlap status.

```
function update() {
    if(game.flags.okoverlap === 1 && !checkOverlap(mushroom, theswitch)) {
        game.flags.okoverlap = 0;
    }
    game.physics.arcade.overlap(mushroom, theswitch, handleCollide, null, this);
}

function checkOverlap(spriteA, spriteB) {
    var boundsA = spriteA.getBounds();
    var boundsB = spriteB.getBounds();

    return Phaser.Rectangle.intersects(boundsA, boundsB);
}
```

The logic inside `handleCollide` function is changed to

```
if (game.flags.okoverlap != 1) {
    game.flags.okoverlap = 1;
    doSwitch();
}
```

Finally replace `okoverlap` in `render` with `game.flags.okoverlap` to prevent `ReferenceError`

```
game.debug.text('overlap: ' + (game.flags.okoverlap == 1 ? 'YES': (game.flags.okoverlap == -1 ? 'partial': 'no')), 20, 40);
```

Working sample here - https://phaser.io/sandbox/edit/ikJBIznv

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this solution uses two separate function to do the same overlap check, the custom `checkOverlap` function as well as the `arcade.overlap` function, which seems redundant. Also, I want to use more than one switch tile in a level, so that makes this solution unpractical.

Comment: @BdR I focused on fixing your bug rather than finding the most performant solution.

Answer (score -1):

I've been playing around some more and found a solution, using 2 global variables. One variable `frameoverlap` to check if there is an overlap, and one variable `doswitch` to see if the switch action was already done. Then you can handle it all in the update() function.

```
function update() {
    // assume no overlap
    frameoverlap = 0;

    // do arcade.overlap
    game.physics.arcade.overlap(mushroom, theswitch, handleCollide, null, this);

    // check flags after arcade.overlap
    if (frameoverlap == 1) {
        if (doswitch == 0) {
            doswitch = 1; // remember the switch was done
            doSwitch();
        }
    } else {
        if (doswitch == 1) {
            doswitch = 0; // stepping off the switch tile
        }
    }
}
```

See updated code here
https://phaser.io/sandbox/edit/VTenTwgh